# Cancelling out surface axis from direction after collision

Tags: c++, collision

Say I am moving (0.5,0.5) into a wall whose surface normal is (-1,0). I want the end result to be (0,0.5), so I cannot continue to move into the wall but slide along the surface.

How can I achieve this? I have

```
comp_u = n * (maths::dot(dir,n) / maths::dot(n,n));
```

which gives me the component of the direction perpendicular to the surface of collision, where 'n' is a vector normal to the surface of collision, and I can cancel this out. However, if I try to move away from the wall, it will cancel that component out to, meaning I can never move away from the wall.

Comment: Slide along the surface? Normally (pun intended) you would be reflected away from the surface. You model this by negating (not zeroing) the normal component. Are you modeling some kind of very anisotropic environment?

Comment: This isn't for anything with physics, just collision response in a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only do the operation if the direction of motion opposes the direction of the normal...  That is, `dot(dir,n)` is negative.

If the result is positive, you are moving away from the wall and you do not modify `dir`.